# Network Simulator for simulation of basic network Topologies (Bus, Ring, Star, Mesh)

Tags: networking, simulation

I was searching for a Network Simulator which can simulate basic Network Topologies (Ring, Star, Bus etc.). I searched so much on net and tried many but they were for the high level making a network topology architecture and working over it with routing and other. I just need a simple simulator by which i can show students about the basic network topologies. Please help me over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a simulator you want, most people I know use GNS3. However that is for layer 3 networks. It can do Layer 2, but only as a switch card in one of the routers.

From what you've said, I think you'd do better to find some animations online. Something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLzo_oCKsxM) maybe?

I'm not sure what this gives you over a whiteboard though, which is how I teach this subject.

Hope this helps,
Alex

Comment: Thank you sir for your way. I didn't got layer 2 simulator anywhere so now i'll use animations. Thanks for help